# HBase and elasticsearch integration like MongoDB river

Tags: rest, hbase, elasticsearch

I am kinda new to both elasticsearch and HBase but for a research project I would like to combine the two. My research project mainly involves searching through large portion of documents (doc,pdf,msg etc) and extracting named entities from the documents through
mapreduce jobs running on the documents stored in HBase.

Does any one know if there is something similar to MongoDB river plugin for HBase? Or can point me to some documentation about integrating ElasticSearch and Hbase? I have looked on the internet for any documentation but unfortunately without any luck.

Kind regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any elasticsearch hbase integrations but there are a few [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and HBase integrations that you can use like [Lily](http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html) and [SolBase](https://github.com/Photobucket/Solbase)

Comment: Tnx for your anwser, yes I know Lily but although it seems to work fine. I was more looking for a more vendor less solution...

Comment: Aah sorry I judged to early. But is seems that even solbase isn't the thing I am looking for either. Solr based upon a schema, the thing I like about elasticsearch it is schema-less. Which allows me to make some column families but am free to fill in the columns values. You see a documents contains different metadata properties then a pdf or msg.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me what you think about this https://github.com/posix4e/Elasticsearch-HBase-River. It uses hbase log shipping to reliably handle updates and deletes from hbase into an elastic search cluster. It could easily be extended to do n regionserver to m elastic search server replication.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org/) jdbc driver + es [jdbc river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) as shown here: http://lessc0de.github.io/connecting_hbase_to_elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any packaged solutions, but as long as your mapreduce preps the data in the right way, it should be fairly easy to write a simple batch job in the programming language of your choice that reads from HBase and submits to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. I have been looking at bagheera from Mozilla, the have some modules that enables them to import documents both into hbase as elasticsearch. Hopefully that wil help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this page (3 years later) :  http://lessc0de.github.io/connecting_hbase_to_elasticsearch.html